# Clients keeps waiting for RabbitMQ response

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

I am using rabbitMQ to launch processes in remote hosts located in other parts of the world. Eg, RabbitMQ is running in an Oregon host, and it receives a client message to launch processes in Ireland and California.

Most of the time, the processes are launched, and, when they finish, rabbitMQ returns the output to the client. But, sometimes, the jobs finish successfully but rabbitMQ hasn't return the output to the client, and the client keeps hanging waiting for the response. These processes can take 10 minutes to execute, so the client is 10 minutes hanged waiting for the response.

I am using `celery` to connect to the rabbitMQ, and the client calls are blocking using `task.get()`. In other words, the client hangs until it receives the response for its call. I would like to understand why the client did not get the response if the jobs have finished. How can I debug this problem?

Here is my `celeryconfig.py`

```
import os
import sys

# add hadoop python to the env, just for the running
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.basename(__file__)))

# broker configuration
# medusa-rabbitmq is the name of the hosts where rabbitmq is running
BROKER_URL = "amqp://celeryuser:celery@medusa-rabbitmq/celeryvhost"

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
TEST_RUNNER = 'celery.contrib.test_runner.run_tests'

# for debug
# CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True

# module loaded
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("medusa.mergedirs", "medusa.medusasystem",
                  "medusa.utility", "medusa.pingdaemon", "medusa.hdfs", "medusa.vote.voting")
```

Comment: you are using celery here - so you are launching tasks, but when you run `task.get()` or whatever the client hangs waiting for the result, even tho the task has been completed by the worker, correct? can you show your celery config?

Comment: you say "These processes can take 10 minutes to execute, so the client is 10 minutes hanged waiting for the response." - this is what you would expect to happen. if you use `task.get()` it blocks until the task has finished running in the celery worker.

Comment: but my question is, why sometimes (not much times), the task finishes but the client is still waiting for the response?

Comment: ok. so sometimes `task.get()` continues to block even tho the task is finished, right? have you tried enabling the rabbitmq web interface and checking to see if the results are updated there. have you tried enabling debugging in the celery worker?

Comment: I only looked to the log of the celery worker, and I simply see that the task have finished. I have rabbitmq web interface enabled, but I don't know how can I see there that rabbitmq have replied to the client.

Comment: rabbitmq does not notify the client - the celery client code polls rabbitmq. enable debugging on the worker. check if your rabbitmq server is under heavy load. try setting `CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = False`